# How is the following Cryptographic Predictability happening?

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, sha

This is the scenario:

Server Key (always 40 chars)
Player1 Key (usually 20 chars) (selected as the first player in the current game)
Player2 Key (usually 20 chars) (selected as the second player in the current game)
Player3 Key (usually 20 chars) (selected as the third player in the current game)
After a plain text-join, an SHA-512 is returned. The first 13 digits of this SHA-512 are converted to Decimal (from Hex). That Decimal is passed through a function roughly as follows:

```
function Transform(hash) {
   let d = parseInt(hash, 16);
   const e = Math.pow(2, 52);
   let r = Math.floor((100 * e - d) / (e - d)) / 100.0
   return r * 0.96
}
```

The return value of r is the gambling result. Needless to say, the house always has an advantage and I cannot understand the maths behind it.

Some other considerations:

An SHA-256 hash of the server key is published before a game. After the game, I verified all the hashes and they are all correct including the real result with the output from the Transform function.

Now, my question is without having any control over the 3 players before the round starts, how does the house maintain a consistent advantage?

P.S.: I have done some digging where I have taken the server key from a high-winning game and then added player keys from low-winning games, and there is no discernible bias towards anything.

Comment: How is the winner determined?  Is it the person who guesses `r` most closely?  Something else?  What is the payout? 2:1?

Comment: Anyone who guesses lower than the generated float but above 1. If the generated number is higher by at least 0.1, the player wins his bet amount times the guess amount.

Answer (score 1):

There's no intrinsic cryptographic advantage in this scheme; it's all in the post-processing and the rules.  First, let's talk about the cryptographic aspects.

It's possible to generate random values, such as for shuffling a deck of cards, by having each person (server included) generate a random value and use what's called a [*commitment scheme*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme) to commit to the value, and then everyone other than the server reveals their random value to the server.  The server hashes the values, including its own, in a deterministic way, and then uses that as the seed.  The seeds are revealed at the end, and we can calculate the value.  The commitment scheme prevents anyone from changing their seed after seeing other values, or from claiming that they submitted a different seed than they did.

That being said, the secure cryptographic hash functions we use in everyday life (usually SHA-2, SHA-3, and BLAKE2) are typically modeled as being indistinguishable from random.  Thus, given the first 13 digits of SHA-512, all values are believed to be equally likely to appear.  So there's something else going on that gives the house an advantage.

You'll notice that 13 hex characters are used.  That means the possible values of `d` are 0 to 2^52 - 1.  If d is 0, then r is 1, and the result is 0.96.  That means that such a game is unwinnable, because nobody can guess more than 1 and still lower than 0.96.  Note that if `d` is the max value, then the result is still less than 2^52, which means even 1 in 2^52 times, you still can't beat the odds.  That's because of the multiplier `0.96`, which gives the house an advantage.

The usage of the `floor` value is also very interesting here, because it gives the house more of an advantage by further lowering the value of `r`.  Remember, the result of this function must be higher than the guess by `0.1` for the guess to win, so since most values are small (the result of the hash input `0x7ffffffffffff`, the midpoint, is 1.98), the user will likely win very little most of the time they do win.